# jQuery datepicker generating an XML error and not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) datepicker in a new application. I am initializing the jQuery and [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //=== Load in any web modules necessary
    google.load("jquery", "1");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1");
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

The input is:

```
<input id="cqupmj" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" value="12-18-2012">
```

My datepicker jQuery control function is defined as follows:

```
var dte = $('#cqupmj').val();
```

Date (dte) input in the format: '12-18-2012'

```
    $( "#cqupmj" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate:  dte,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        //dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        //dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        altFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        onSelect: quote.get_date
    });
```

The XML error is as follows:

```
Error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid1-f9uj2thwoam5gq-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/system/events.js", line 58, in 
data: data
File "resource://jid1-f9uj2thwoam5gq-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/observer-service.js", line 35, in listener
callback.call(target || callback, subject, data);
File "resource://jid1-f9uj2thwoam5gq-at-jetpack/collusion/lib/main.js", line 395, in 
queueInfo(connection);
File "resource://jid1-f9uj2thwoam5gq-at-jetpack/collusion/lib/main.js", line 197, in queueInfo
if (types.indexOf(info.type) == -1) {
TypeError: types is undefined
```

These datepickers worked at one time and now do not. The code did not change, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. How do I fix it?

Comment: why you call this XML error ?

Comment: It maybe some issue with files you load from google service. Have you tried downloading the most recent version of jQuery and referencing it localy?

Comment: what is quote ? object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `hasDatepicker` class from your code,

```
<input id="cqupmj" type="text" value="12-18-2012">
```

The default date is also not needed if you take it from same input. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fM3gr/).

The date format should be also `mm-dd-yy`, not `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Also be sure to wrap your init functions with `$(function() {/*INIT CODE*/}`.

The errors you are getting seems to come from your browser extensions errors, not your page.